# Rails - one model with two associations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

I have the model `Member` that contains all informations about the registered member on my site. Then I have the model `Message` which contains 2 columns (actually 3 with `id`):

```
- member_id
- message_from
```

In the table `Messages` are stored IDs of user, how chatting together - when the member **A** send message to member **B**, so in the column `member_id` is saved ID of person **A** and into the column `message_from` ID of the person **B**.

My current associations looks like:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages_from
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
end
```

I don't know, how could I get the name of the person stored in the column **message_from** - when I try

```
- @member.messages_from.each do |mess_from|
    ={mess_from.name}
```

so I get the error `undefined method "name" for`... How could I get the name of the user through ID that is stored in the column `message_from`?

**EDIT** - update relations:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member, :foreign_key => 'user_id', :class_name => 'Member'
  has_one :member, :foreign_key => 'message_from', :class_name => 'Member'
end
```

gives me:

```
- @member.messages.each do |message|
    = message.message_from.inspect # => "110"
    = message.message_from.inspect # => undefined method `name' for "110":String (I wanna get the name of person with ID 110)
```

Comment: I dint understand your **-** and **=** signs, but Shouldnt that be `member.name` instead of `mess_from.name` Coz messages dont have name rather its the member entry which has the name ;)

Comment: You want `has_many :messages` along with a foreign key specification.

Comment: @MarkThomas I tried to update the code by your advice and updated my original post

Comment: You're using `has_one :member` and `belongs_to :member` at the at the same time. This will clash. In your view you access `message.message_from.name` insted of `message.member.name`. (Here you see the clash, what's member? Sender, Receiver?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
# Untested code, please check yourself!
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :outgoing_messages, :class_name  => "Message", 
                               :foreign_key => :message_from_id
  has_many :incoming_messages, :class_name  => "Message",
                               :foreign_key => :message_to_id
end


class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name  => "Member", 
                      :foreign_key => :message_from_id
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name  => "Member", 
                        :foreign_key => :message_to_id
end
```

More to read about associations here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

EDIT: In your views:

```
- @member.outgoing_messages.each do |message|
    ={message.receiver.name}
    ={message.sender.name}
```