# Rails form with two fields on same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-attributes

Trying to implement something like in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934308/rails-one-model-with-two-associations)

I think my intention is best explained with a simple example. Let's say, I've got a three values (all objects of the same model, say `Users`), "Peter", "John" and "Thurse".
I want my form to contain two fields, `:regular_user` and `:commander_user`. For both fields I want to select from model `User` (so, both `select_tags` should contain same values- Peter, John and Thurse). So my goal is to select Peter and John for regular users and Thurse for commander. 
Additionally, let's say the form is for the model `Game`. The binding model would be `GameUser` in this case.
So basically what I want is to call `my_game.regular_users` and receive "Peter" and "John" and to call `my_game.commanders` and receive "Thurse".

Word description of my actual structure is following: I've got menus (like in a restaurant) and each menu can have different amount of persons attached to it. This model is called `Personamount` and they are connected via `Menupersonamount` and a `has_many through` relationship.

Works just fine for one field. But I need to save some different entries from `Personamount` in the same form.

Here is the code:

Form:

```
 .row
      .col-md-12
            / Select for how many persons this menu can be bought for
            .section.row
              %label.field.prepend-field
                =f.collection_select(:personamount_ids, Personamount.all, :id, :title, {include_blank: false, :include_hidden => false, :selected => @menu.personamounts.map(&:id)}, { class: 'select2-multiple form-control select-info select-personamount', :multiple => true})

        .row
          .col-sm-12
            .section.row
              %label.field.prepend-field
                =f.collection_select(:bonus_personamount_ids, Personamount.all, :id, :title, {include_blank: false, :include_hidden => false}, { class: 'select2-multiple form-control select-info select-bonus-personamount', :multiple => true})
```

Menu.rb:

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menupersonamounts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :personamounts, through: :menupersonamounts
  has_many :bonus_personamounts, through: :menupersonamounts, :class_name  => "Personamount", :foreign_key => :bonus_personamount_id
end
```

Menupersonamount.rb:

```
class Menupersonamount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :menu
  belongs_to :personamount, :class_name  => "Personamount", :foreign_key => :personamount_id
  belongs_to :bonus_personamount, :class_name  => "Personamount", :foreign_key => :bonus_personamount_id
end
```

Personamount.rb:

```
class Personamount < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :menupersonamounts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :menus, through: :menupersonamounts

  has_many  :dinner_amount_options, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :dinner_amount_options, allow_destroy: true
end
```

This is my error:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "menupersonamounts" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_d94bf3abd0"
DETAIL:  Key (bonus_personamount_id)=(13) is not present in table "bonus_personamounts".
: INSERT INTO "menupersonamounts" ("menu_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "bonus_personamount_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"):

app/controllers/admin/menus_controller.rb:33:in `update'
```

Well, it's obvious, that there is no table `bonus_personamounts`, but if I change `foreign_key_id` from `bonus_personamount_id` to `personamount_id`, the form just saves two same values.

So, again - I need to save values from same table, `Personamount` into two different fields within one form.

**Update 1:**

Menu.rb

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menupersonamounts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bonusmenupersonamounts, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "Menupersonamount", foreign_key: :bonuspersonamount_id

  has_many :personamounts, through: :menupersonamounts
  has_many :bonuspersonamounts, through: :bonusmenupersonamounts
end
```

Personamount.rb

```
class Personamount < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :menupersonamounts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bonusmenupersonamounts, :class_name => 'Menupersonamount', :foreign_key => :bonuspersonamount_id

  has_many :menus, through: :menupersonamounts
  has_many :menus, through: :bonusmenupersonamounts

  has_many  :dinner_amount_options, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :dinner_amount_options, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Menupersonamount.rb

```
class Menupersonamount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :menu
  belongs_to :personamount
  belongs_to :bonuspersonamount, :class_name  => "Personamount", foreign_key: :bonuspersonamount_id
end
```

menus_controller.rb

```
def update
    if @menu.update(menu_params)
        redirect_to edit_admin_menu_path(@menu), method: :get
        flash[:success] = "Updated!"
    else
        render "edit"
    end
end

private

def menu_params
    params.require(:menu).permit(:category_id, :price, :daterange, :hotpic, :remove_hotpic,
        { delivery_ids: [] }, { recipe_ids: [] }, { personamount_ids: [] }, { bonuspersonamount_ids: [] }, { day_ids: [] }, :change_from, 
        :change_to, :description, :has_dessert, :has_breakfast,
  menurecipes_attributes: [:id, :sortable, :menu_id, :recipe_id, :_destroy, recipe_attributes: [:id, :_destroy]]

  )
end
```

Comment: wait you want to assign multiple personamountids to the menus ? `belongs_to` requires a single id. I think you should post your schema, and explain what you exactly try to do. I'll delete my answer since it is useless under these circumstances.

Comment: Updated my answer (third paragraph). However, now I found a major mistake - previously I indeed created a model named `BonusPersonamount` and a corresponding table. This led to my previous errors. But right now, I'm not able to save those `bonus_personamounts`. Since it's a bit too much console output text, I'll post the console output as link to a screenshot - http://take.ms/DIqhf

Comment: One of your problems is (seen in the console output) that you try to assign multiple personamounts to the menu record. the menu record has a `belongs_to` so it can only "hold" one personamount. Sorry have to go, will look back as soon as i can, i hope somebody can help you meanwhile

Comment: But it works for the regular personamount - http://take.ms/uwguV

Comment: aah sorry my bad, I think now I got what you want. You wannt to choose multiple `personamounts` and multiple `bonuspersonamounts` in one go ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, and i think this should make clear where your problem lies. I really hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think now I understand the problem here. You have a class Menu's which has multiple Menuspersonamounts. Menupersonamounts can hold one `personamounts` and one `bonuspersonamount` that is no problem if they are created serially.

It also works with only one field because, if multiple `personamounts` are set (1,2) for example, rails creates n (in the example 2) `Menupersonamounts` records:

```
Menupersonamounts1: { personamounts: 1 }
Menupersonamounts2: { personamounts: 2 }
```

Now let's assume we submit the same two `personamounts` (1,2) and also a `bonuspersonamount` (1). Now it is not determinable how to save that:

```
Menupersonamounts1: { personamounts: 1, bonuspersonamounts: 1 }
Menupersonamounts2: { personamounts: 2 }
```

Or:

```
Menupersonamouns1: { personamounts: 1 }
Menupersonamount2: { personamounts: 2, bonuspersonamounts: 1 }
```

This gets worse the more id's are selected. So there are two possibilities. Handle the mappings of the id's for yourself, or handle the `Menupersonamounts` creation serially, so just give the possibility to select one `personamount` and one `bonuspersonamount`.

Comment: I tried a lot of combinations, ended up with my `Update 1`. Still getting the error `ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "menupersonamounts" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_d94bf3abd0"
DETAIL:  Key (bonus_personamount_id)=(13) is not present in table "bonus_personamounts".
: INSERT INTO "menupersonamounts" ("created_at", "updated_at", "bonus_personamount_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"):
`

Comment: can you also post your menu controller, where the error happens ?

Comment: Updated my answer with important parts (`update` method and `params`). Btw. - I changed everything where the underscore appears not to use this underscore. But the error is still the same: `ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "menupersonamounts" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_d94bf3abd0"
DETAIL:  Key (bonuspersonamount_id)=(13) is not present in table "bonus_personamounts".
: INSERT INTO "menupersonamounts" ("created_at", "updated_at", "bonuspersonamount_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"):
`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your anwer correctly. I'm editing only one Menu at a time. So, if `personamounts` have ids of (1,2) and `bonuspersonamounts` aswell ids of (1,2), it should be perfectly fine to  save them this way. Meaning `@menu.personamount_ids` should equal (1,2) and `@menu.bonuspersonamount_ids` should also equal (1,2).

But I guess it will be easier just to create a model `BonusPersonamount` in addition to `Personamount` and duplicate all the code.

Comment: don't do that. Sorry i have taken the wrong class, i mean `menuspersonamounts` not `menus` just look again at the answer.